# Não estou conseguindo chamar informações do usuário

Tags: php, pdo

**User.php**

```
<?php
    class User {
        public static $Row = [];

        public static function Check() {
            global $PDO;

            $usersql = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1");
            $usersql->execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['username'], ':password' => $_SESSION['password']));

            $Row = $usersql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            self::$Row = $Row;
        }
    }
```

**Index.php**

```
echo 'Você é '. User::$Row['username'];
```

E erro que dá:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Index.php on line 1

Ele aparece na `index.php` em `Check()`, quando tento chamar informações do usuário dá esse erro.

Alguém sabe como resolvo?

Comment: você precisa chamar o `check()` antes de : `echo 'Você é '. User::$Row['username'];`

Comment: Faz assim: `User::Check(); echo User::$Row['username'];`

Comment: obrigado rray, vc salvou minha vida!

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29761/discussion-on-question-by-tools-nao-estou-conseguindo-chamar-informacoes-do-usua)

Answer (score 1):

Pelos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89626/n%C3%A3o-estou-conseguindo-chamar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-usu%C3%A1rio#comment181237_89626) e pela mensagem de erro `Undefined index: username in`, foi concluído que o problema era no arquivo index.php que estava dessa forma:

index.php

```
<?php
   require 'User.php';
   echo 'Você é '. User::$Row['username'];
```

Porém `$Row` só terá seu valor definido após a chamada do método `Check()`. O ajuste do index foi:

```
<?php
   require 'User.php';
   User::Check(); //método que define o valor de $Row
   echo 'Você é '. User::$Row['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que o problema está na atribuição dos valores ao `SELECT`. Eu costumo usar o `bindValue` para setar os valores à string do SQL. Tente isto:

```
<?php
    class User {
        public static $Row = [];
        public static function Check() {
            global $PDO;

            $usersql = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1");
            $usersql->bindValue(":username", $_SESSION['username']);
            $usersql->bindValue(":password", $_SESSION['password']);
            $usersql->execute();

            $Row = $usersql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            self::$Row = $Row;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: acho q  o problema é q n está reconhecendo o $Row do User.php

Comment: teste o conteúdo da função fora da classe, tente imprimir os valores que vêm do banco para ter certeza de que não é problema com o `SELECT` ou algo do tipo.

Comment: tentei imprimir o conteúdo na index.php com o echo User::$Row['username']; só q deu error Notice: Undefined